# mysql union statement failing because of bracket placement?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have written three working sql statement, and am trying to use a union like this:

```
(SELECT * FROM articles WHERE date <= '2015-01-15' AND category='News' )
UNION
(SELECT * FROM articles WHERE date <= '2015-01-15' AND subcategory='News')
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5
UNION
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE Month(recurring) = '01' AND category='News' ORDER BY 
recurring DESC LIMIT 5
```

The basic structure is what I'm asking about: two initial queries unioned and sorted together by date.
Then a third query, sorted by a separate column, and then  unioned into the first two.

The query above seems to work fine when I sort the first 2 queries inside the brackets separately, but fails once I take it out of the brackets and sort them together.

Is sorting by a separate column causing it to fail?  I tried adding an additional set of brackets to encapsulate the first 2 statements plus the sort order, but no go.
Here is the error code:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION SELECT * FROM articles WHERE Month(recurring) = '01' AND category='News' at line 2

Comment: Have you tried adding a parenthesis around the original `UNION`, all the way to the second one? `((Select ... LIMIT 5) UNION`

Comment: Yes, thats one of the first things.  It does shift the return  error to 'at line 1' but same basic error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your query. An UNION query can only have one LIMIT clause and one ORDER BY clause, and both are applied to the whole result.

If I understand your logic correctly, I would rewrite your query as this:

```
(
  SELECT * FROM articles
  WHERE date <= '2015-01-15' AND (category='News' OR subcategory='News')
  ORDER BY date DESC
  LIMIT 5
)
UNION
(
  SELECT * FROM articles
  WHERE Month(recurring) = '01' AND category='News'
  ORDER BY recurring DESC
  LIMIT 5
)
```

if your query is more complicated and you really want your first two queries to be separated, this is the right syntax to use:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM articles WHERE date <= '2015-01-15' AND category='News'
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM articles WHERE date <= '2015-01-15' AND subcategory='News'
    ORDER BY date DESC
    LIMIT 5
) AS s
UNION
(
  SELECT * FROM articles
  WHERE Month(recurring) = '01' AND category='News'
  ORDER BY recurring DESC
  LIMIT 5
)
```